# Laravel - How to collect multiple array to single one

Tags: php, laravel, collections

I've created a collection like this :

```
Collection {#651 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "orderId" => "402457"
      "orderCreated" => DateTime {#656 ▶}
      "foods" => array:2 [▶]
    ]
    1 => array:3 [▼
      "orderId" => "402457"
      "orderCreated" => DateTime {#661 ▶}
      "foods" => array:2 [▶]
    ]
    2 => array:3 [▼
      "orderId" => "402457"
      "orderCreated" => DateTime {#665 ▶}
      "foods" => array:2 [▶]
    ]
  ]
}
```

I demand to achieve collection like this (with Laravel collection):

```
Collection {#651 ▼
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => array:3 [▼
      "orderId" => "402457"
      "orderCreated" => DateTime {#656 ▶}
      "foods" => array:6 [▶]
    ]

  ]
}
```

Because orderId and orderCreated are all the same in arrays. I need to make single array that collect orderId and orderCreated with all foods.
Any suggestion?

Comment: can you provide more info about *how* you create said collection, and what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the data from the first one and just combine all of the food items. For instance like this:

```
$new = collect([
    'orderId' => $old->first()->orderId,
    'orderCreated' => $old->first()->orderCreated,
    'foods' => $old->pluck('foods')->flatten(1),
]);
```

The exact implementation will depend on how you built your initial collection.